# What does $d\Omega$ signify?

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain to me what does $d\Omega$ mean in this integral?
$$\int_\Omega\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x) \ d\Omega$$
I have never seen that; we always use $dx,dt...$

Comment: d$\Omega$ is the area or volume form on $\Omega$, expressed independently of coordinates.

Comment: volume form on $\Omega$ ??? didn t really understand

Answer (score 3):

It simply means a differential element of the region of integration, $\Omega$. So, for instance, if your region of integration is an area, $A$, then we could write the integral of a function over that area as:
$$\int_A f(x) dA$$
To express that in coordinates, we would write (for example) $dA=dx\,dy$ for Cartesian coordinates or $dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$ for cylindrical coordinates.

In more advanced treatments, we would say that $d\Omega$ is a certain *differential form* over the region of integration - this would come up for defining integrals on general differentiable manifolds.

Comment: @ Matt Dickau well done thank you very much , but what about this one , in the green's formula we have on the right  side of the equality $$\int_{\partial\Omega}uvnd\sigma$$ this $d\sigma$ is littl bit not clear

Comment: In Green's formula you integrate over the boundary $\partial\Omega$ of some region $\Omega$. So $d\sigma$ refers to a differential element of the boundary of $\Omega$. $n$ probably refers to the unit normal vector to that boundary element (that is, the vector that points away from $\Omega$ at that point on the boundary).